# Session data object is conflicting sometimes between 2 or more sessions in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

My application is running under tomcat. And i'm maintaining one server object for every session. But the problem is when connected from different sessions from different users sometimes my server object is conflicting means i'm getting data of another session which is currently connected to the tomcat server. 
Please help me to get out of this issue.

My application has been done using MVC architecture. So, every action/request performed by user on webpage will come to controller page. On top of controller every time i'll get my object and i'll use this object to get data from server which is running as a java service.It will like beloww...

```
<jsp:useBean id="conn" scope="session" class="myconclass" />

<% MyObjClass mObjName = conn.getMyObj(); %>
```

Here 'mObjName' will be used throughout the controller. And when i found this issue (when connected many users), i have started printing this object in someplaces and i see this is object is changing and returnning results of another session.

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using? Can you show an example of code using session objects that happen to conflict?

Comment: let us show what you did practically to be in better position to sort out your problem. You not provided enough information to help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply description updated and using version 5.5